# Fourier heat conduction and temperature gradient

Tags: thermodynamics

I am studying introductory heat behaivuor, and I came across a rather elementary problem. Say there is a wall and constant temperature differential maintained on either side of the wall. I read that a linear temperature gradient within the wall results, but I don't know how I would derive/figure this out?

I can think of one numeric way to do this, splitting the wall into many many tiny elements, setting them all to any temperature T_0, and then performing an iterative numeric pattern around every element, averaging surrounding temperature. This doesn't use very much reasoning, and I was hoping for a more Physics-based answer. Any ideas?

Comment: if you explicitly write down the averaging you speak of, and take the limit of zero lenght, you actually get [Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Statement_of_the_equation) (which is the PDE that models the heat flow of your problem, $T''(x)=0$).

Comment: The key thing that's missing is that the linear gradient results *at steady state*. If you set the time derivative of temperature to 0 in a block of material with constant diffusivity, you immediately find that the second spatial derivative (i.e. the Laplacian, in this one-dimensional case) is also zero. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This doesn't use very much reasoning, and I was hoping for a more Physics-based answer. Any ideas?

The linear temperature gradient is simply the consequence of [Fourier's Law of heat conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Differential_form):

$$\vec{q}=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$$

Where $\vec{q}$ is the local heat flux density, which is equal to the product of thermal conductivity, $k$ and the negative of the local temperature gradient $\frac{dT}{dx}$. Integrated, $\Delta T$ becomes a linear function of $x$, so:

$$\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}=-\frac{\vec{q}}{k}$$

If $\vec{q}=\text{constant}$.

Comment: @djax1234, what was so "physics based" about your iterative method approach?

Comment: point was it wasn;t physics based, just numeric.

Answer (score 0):

As @AccidentalFourierTransform indicated, you can do this explicitly, rather than solving a set of equations iteratively.  The equation for the local heat flux (heat flow per unit area) at location x within the wall is given by:
$$q=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$$
If we multiply by the total cross sectional area of the wall A, we get the total rate of heat flow Q:
$$-kA\frac{dT}{dx}=qA=Q \tag{1}$$
Note that, at steady state, the total rate of heat flow Q does not vary with x because the heat goes straight through and does not accumulate anywhere.  So Eqn. 1 is a first order linear differential equation for the temperature as a function of x, subject to the temperature boundary conditions on the inner and outer surfaces of the wall.  This gives:
$$T=T(0)+(T(L)-T(0))\frac{x}{L}$$ with $$Q=kA\frac{T(0)-T(L)}{L}$$